# Expectation of a random walk that can't go below zero

Tags: expected-value, random-walk

Suppose we have a random walk $S_n$ that is constrained to be positive or zero, that is:

$$S_0 > 0$$

$$S_{i+1} = \max(S_i+x_i,\space 0)$$

$$x_i \sim N[\mu,\sigma^2]$$

Can we analytically determine the expectation $\operatorname E[S_n]$ as a function of $S_0,n,\mu,\sigma$? How?

Comment: Hint: find an expression for $E[S_{n+1}]$ in terms of $E[S_n].$

Comment: Suggest simplify the problem to $S_0 = 0$, $\mu = 0$, and $\sigma = 1$.

Comment: Please add a `self-study` tag.

Comment: I don't think this is a self-study problem, in the sense that the term is usually used to denote homework. I think it is an interesting problem, especially to solve for the desired expectation as $n$ becomes large. It is essentially a problem in summing censored Normal random variables, each time with a new location parameter. An interesting feature of the problem is that if the random walk escapes 0 and becomes large, then the censoring at 0 becomes largely irrelevant, and it reverts to becoming a common discrete time Gaussian random walk. But if the random walk heads back to 0, then it binds

Comment: I confirm it's no homework :)